# Indistinguishable Obfuscation vs Functional Encryption

Tags: functional-encryption, io

What is the difference between Functional Encryption from Indistinguishable Obfuscation? Is one of them having more stronger security than the other?

Answer (score 4):

These are equivalent primitives *assuming* the existence of one-way functions, which implies $\mathbf{P}\neq\mathbf{NP}$$^*$. It was shown in [G+,SW] that IO plus OWFs implies public-key FE.$^{**}$ The converse, that sub-exponentially-secure public-key FE (with some succinctness property) implies IO, was shown in [BV].

On the other hand, as pointed out in the comment by @integrator, if $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{NP}$ then IO exists (simply pick the smallest/lexicographically-first circuit which computes the same function) but FE (which implies PKE) does not.

$^*$This was relaxed to $\mathbf{NP}\not\subseteq \mathbf{io}- \mathbf{BPP}$ in [K+].

$^{**}$[G+] assume PKE and NIZK in addition to IO. These were later shown to be implied by IO and OWFs [SW].

[BV] Bitansky and Vaikuntanathan, [Indistinguishability Obfuscation from Functional Encryption](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/163), FOCS'15

[G+] Garg et al, [Candidate indistinguishability obfuscation and functional encryption for all circuits](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/451), FOCS'13.

[K+] Komargodski et al, [One-Way Functions and (Im)perfect Obfuscation](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/347), FOCS'14

[SW] Sahai and Waters,  [How to Use Indistinguishability Obfuscation: Deniable Encryption, and More](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/454), STOC'14

Comment: It's a bit of a shortcut to say they are equivalent, as other primitives such as NIZKs or PKE are used in both directions. And in fact if P=NP then iO for all circuits exists but Functional Encryption does not.

Comment: [BV] says that "public-key functional encryption with succinct encryption circuits and subexponential security" implies iO. I am wondering if standard/existing FE constructions are subexponential secure and succinct...

Comment: @integrator: True that. But whenever one talks about IO, one implicitly assumes OWFs, which implies $\mathbf{P}\neq\mathbf{NP}$, (as IO by itself is not very useful.). And IO+OWF implies PKE/NIZK (Sahai and Waters, STOC'14).  Will amend the answer to make this more explicit.

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira: Good point. Will take another look at [BV].